# cant compare 0 in a conditional statement in js

Tags: javascript, string, node.js, conditional-statements

well this is in node to be exact but, when i do the following conditional statement on a string of a length of zero or above zero, it will only ever do the condition if the string is not 0.

```
if(string.length == 0)
{
   console.log(string.length)
} else {
   console.log(string.length)
};
```

no matter what it wont respond if the string.length is 0. i have also tried:

```
if(string.length > 0)
{
    console.log('greater than zero')
} else {
    console.log('zero')
};
```

but with the same results. no matter what it wont respond if the string.length is zero. i have printed the string.length outside of the if/else statement, and have been able to have it print 0. why wont the conditional statement work in this case? why does it just not respond if the string.length == 0?

Comment: Please show how you are defining/declaring the variable `string`. Did you verify that it is neither `null` nor `undefined`?

Comment: string is defined as a string of words. for example 'hello how are you' and yes i have confirmed as i was able to print the length outside of the if/else but was unable to within if it was 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was getting whitespace if the string was 0. i solved the error by doing string.trim()

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work.  [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/VCDxj/)  Firebug records a 0 if there is nothing in the `<div>`